# Special mouse and keyboard keys stopped working

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 17.10

Since my upgrade to 17.10, the following has stopped working:

- Special keys on the keyboard, such as Volume up/down, Calculator, Files, Search, etc..
- Ctrl+Alt+t doesn't open terminal
- Special keys on the mouse; the two back and forward keys on the side

All of these keys always worked all the way to 17.04.

Note: I'm still using Unity, which didn't actually get removed on the upgrade as it said it would. Gnome on Wayland didn't start for me, and neither did Gnome on Xorg after I upgraded my nvidia drivers to 384 (I have yet to try with 387)

What's going on?

Comment: Wayland doesn't (yet) work with proprietary drivers so, for the moment, forget about it. Xorg should still work.

Comment: When I log into gnome on xorg, the screen goes black for a while, then goes back to lightdm (I have also tried gdm). When I go back to unity, it complains that my monitor size is invalid, which is fixed by deleting `.config/monitors.xml`. Honestly, this particular upgrade of ubuntu has been a disaster (unlike all previous upgrades which game _me_ maximum one or two minor issues)

Comment: A disaster, agreed. So, better backup and do a fresh install. If the synptom persists then we have something to think about.

Comment: Sigh... I didn't switch to Linux to have to reinstall my OS every year like I had to...